# How to find the mean of a time column and group it using r?

Tags: r, dataframe, time, group-by, lubridate

I have a data frame containing a column named ride_length which is already in hh:mm:ss format. I would like to calculate the mean from that column and group it via its two category: member and casual (found in the member_casual column).

I have tried this pipeline with the lubridate library:

```
df %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>%
  seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length))))
```

Even if my arguments are the same as other examples found online, I still get this message:

Error in seconds_to_period(., mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length)))) :
unused argument (mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length))))

I have also tried a longer path by doing this:

```
df$nride_length <- difftime(strptime(df$ride_length,"%H:%M:%S"),
                     strptime("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S"),
                     units="mins")
df.means <- aggregate(df$nride_length,by=list(df$member_casual),mean)
df.means$ride_length <- format(.POSIXct(df.means$x,tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")
df.means
```

But the result is still problematic:

Group.1       x ride_length
1  casual NA mins        
2  member NA mins

I have also tried with summarise:

```
df %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>%
  summarise(length_mean = seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length)))))
```

But then this shows:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  member_casual length_mean
  <chr>         <Period>   
1 casual        NA         
2 member        NA         

Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `summarise()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `length_mean =
  seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length))))`.
ℹ In group 1: `member_casual = "casual"`.
Caused by warning in `.parse_hms()`:
! Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning.
```

Please help

Comment: I tried with mutate but I didn't get what I expected:
# A tibble: 5,021,491 × 17
# Groups:   member_casual [2]
...
Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `foo_mean =
  seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(hms(ride_length))))`.
ℹ In group 1: `member_casual = "casual"`.
Caused by warning in `.parse_hms()`:
! Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning.

Comment: Could you share (part of) your data? Something like `dput(head(df))`

Comment: It's difficult to follow code and errors in comments, please add additional details and code updates to your question -- you can still edit it. For aggregating you'd want to use `summarise()`  instead of `mutate()`

Comment: structure(list(rideable_type = c("electric_bike", "classic_bike", "classic_bike", 
"electric_bike", "classic_bike", "classic_bike"), day_of_week = c(1, 
1, 1, 6, 7, 2), ride_length = structure(c(990, 
810, 576, 296, 686, 294), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), member_casual = c("member", 
    "member", "member", "member", "member", "member"), nride_length = structure(c(16.5, 
    13.5, 9.6, 4.93, 11.43, 4.9), class = "difftime", units = "mins")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` alone. Specify the grouping as you'd do with an anova. I changed the data.frame a little so there are three of both "member" and "casual".

```
dtf <- structure(list(rideable_type=c("electric_bike",
  "classic_bike", "classic_bike", "electric_bike",
  "classic_bike", "classic_bike"), day_of_week=c(1, 1, 1, 6, 7,
  2), ride_length=structure(c(990, 810, 576, 296, 686, 294),
  class=c("hms", "difftime"), units="secs"),
  member_casual=c("member", "member", "member", "casual",
  "casual", "casual"), nride_length=structure(c(16.5, 13.5, 9.6,
  4.93, 11.43, 4.9), class="difftime", units="mins")),
  row.names=c(NA, -6L), class=c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
    
aggregate(ride_length ~ member_casual, data=dtf, mean)
  #   member_casual    ride_length
  # 1        casual 425.33333 secs
  # 2        member 792.00000 secs
```

Comment: The aggregate function worked! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Assume your data as below:

```
x <- c("09:10:01", "10:10:02", "09:40:03","07:10:16", "09:20:02", "08:52:10")
df <- data.frame(member_casual=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3)),
                   ride_length=hms(x),stringsAsFactors = F)

df
  member_casual ride_length
1             A   9H 10M 1S
2             A  10H 10M 2S
3             A   9H 40M 3S
4             B  7H 10M 16S
5             B   9H 20M 2S
6             B  8H 52M 10S
```

i tried the codes you tried above and it works well for me.

```
df %>%
   group_by(member_casual) %>%
   summarise(mean=seconds_to_period(mean(period_to_seconds(ride_length))))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  member_casual mean                    
  <chr>         <Period>                
1 A             9H 40M 2S               
2 B             8H 27M 29.3333333333321S
```

so please confirmed your data have right format, especially the column named 'ride_length', run the `hms(df$ride_length)` alone and check if it run successfully.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer OP's question as it makes assumptions - namely the format of the data - that OP needs to confirm.  better to ask OP for test data in a comment and then provide an answer based on what they give you.